# How float and position work together?

Tags: html, css

In the below code,

```
<div class="box" id="one">One</div>
<div class="box" id="two">Two</div>
<div class="box" id="three">Three</div>
<div class="box" id="four">Four</div>
```

---

```
.box { 
   display: inline-block; 
   background: red; 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px; 
   float: left; 
   color: black; 
}

#one{
    background: red;
}
#two { 
   position: absolute;
   background: yellow; 
}
#three{
    background: green;
}
#four{
    background: blue;
}
```

--

box "two" being absolutely positioned and being away from the flow of the document, box "three" & "four" are taking place of box "two", due to which, box "two" is displaced as last element, as shown below, which looks good,

### [image]

But in the below code,

```
<div id="parent-div">
      <div id="default">Default</div>
      <div id="centered">Centered</div>
      <div id="centered-text">Centered Text</div>
    </div>

   <div id="top-left-pos">Top Left

    </div>

    <div id="another-pos">Another pos
    </div>
```

---

```
#parent-div{
    background: #B3bEb5;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
}

#default{
  background: #DBE9F4;
}
#centered{
  background: #89CFF0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* text-align: left, right, center, justify */
#centered-text{
  text-align: center;
}

/* Absolute Positioning : Positioning Based on the Document */
#top-left-pos{
  background: #89CFF0;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;   
}


#another-pos{
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 190px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

---

`top-left-pos` element is absolutely positioned and away from the flow of the document, `another-pos` element does take the place of `top-left-pos` element but does not displace `top-left-pos` element? instead `another-pos` element is rendered beneath `top-left-pos` element, as shown below, Why `top-left-pos` is not displaced, unlike first scenario of box "two"?

[image]

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: @shennan [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8m1nvqL/3/) is the code tested. Am trying to understand the stack level of `yellow` element.

Comment: floating uses document flow, absolute position not. You can't to combine it.

Comment: Box "three" gets overlayed by "two" since it's defined as `absolute positioned`. It's not possible to combine as you think it is.

Comment: @PhilM. Why Box "three" overlays "two"? I mean, why box "two" is displaced from its position as  last element?

Comment: @overexchange because it has been taken out of the flow of the document using `position:absolute;`

Comment: @shennan *because it has been taken out of the flow of the document using `position:absolute`?*  why `top-left-pos` in this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5pq4kz/1) is not displaced for `another-pos` element?

Comment: @overexchange you would do well to read and consider all the comments and the answer. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5pq4kz/2/) is your fiddle updated with a `z-index`. Now you can see that the element is 'stacked' on top of the `another-pos` element.

Comment: @shennan As you said [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939322/how-float-and-position-work-together#comment55637872_33939322), box "three" overlay box "two", Am asking, why `another-pos` element did not overlay `top-left-pos` element [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5pq4kz/1/)?Using `z-index` to change the stack level is different topic.

Comment: @overexchange please define the difference between 'overlay' and 'stack level'?

Comment: @shennan Please see the question edited

Answer (score 6):

> How float and position work together?

They don't. An absolutely positioned element cannot float. A floating element cannot be absolutely positioned.

When an element is specified to both float *and* `position: absolute`, the latter takes precedence and the element does *not* float. Though unrelated, the `float: left` in your first scenario takes precedence over the `display: inline-block` as well. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) has an entire subsection detailing how `display`, `position` and `float` work together.

> Why `top-left-pos` is not displaced, unlike first scenario of box "two"?

Because box "two" in your first scenario is being displaced by floating elements. In your second scenario, there are no floats to displace that element. All you have are two absolutely positioned elements that are unaware of each other.

Comment: No floats to displace? `top-left-pos` has float property

Comment: @overexchange yes, and it also has `position: absolute`, which causes the float not to work. You should really pay more attention to what people are explaining to you.

Comment: But in MDN, these examples are using both `position` and `float` for each element.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Examples  Is this wrong documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Float is nothing to to do with stacking elements in a 3D environment. As per the [explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

You may be wanting the `z-index` property instead, if you're looking to stack your elements on top of one another. You will also need to take them out of flow in order to do this, by using `position:absolute`.

***Update***

Frustratingly, you've edited your original question with some quite major changes. The crux of these changes begs the question:

> What is the relationship between float, position and display?

Thankfully, you can go and [read-up about that here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). Please do so. Stack Overflow is not a place you can come to learn *everything* you want to know about *anything*.

Comment: Good explanation. An element "floats" in a 2d environment, not a 3d environment. Consequently, it cannot float above or below another element. It can, however, float to the left or to the right of another element. To position an element above or below another element, use a higher or a lower `z-index`.

Comment: @Rounin Cannot float above or below? Please see this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/u89g1g9b/1/)

Comment: Haha. Very good, @overexchange. But, this browser-determined stack-order is arbitrary, isn't it? We know that floated box `#one` is outside document flow and takes up no space within the document flow. Consequently, in this instance, both boxes occupy the same area (having a top-left corner starting at co-ordinates [0,0]) and the browser has - you're right! - stacked them 3-dimensionally... but not in any way that you or I could actually control, right? I bet - without introducing a z-index declaration - you can't produce the same result with floated box `#one` beneath non-floated box `#two`?

Comment: @Rounin: It's not even determined by the browser alone, but by the spec, though no less arbitrary - see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers